# jQuery - Change name of an input field by using value of another input field filled at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a dynamic form where you can add or delete fields, [Here you can find the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qN3eu/1/)
The first button you find is `Add Metric`. From this the code generates:

- Input Field `Metric`
- Button `Add Tag`

Inside this field a user can add a tag with the button `Add Tag`, generated when you click add Metric. When you click `Add Tag` button, two fields are generated:

- Input Field `Id`
- Input Field `Value`

The Html code that I need to generate in order to serialize the entire form (this is not however the question point) will result like this:

```
<input type="text" name="metrics[0][name]" value="Text 0"> // Metric
<input type="text" id="TagId0" name=" "> //Tag Id
<input type="text" id="TagValue" name="metrics[0][tags][][0]">
```

**Problem:**
I need that (when I fill the field with `id="TagId0"`) the value I select will go immediately to the field name with `id="TagValue"`. This field must result like this:

Consider I write on `TagId0` the word "hello", field will become:

```
<input type="text" id="TagValue" name="metrics[0][tags][hello][0]">
```

How, if it's possible, it can be done?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question correctly. You want that when you type the text into the field, it pulls that value and adds it into the name attribute, where you have put the word hello? Sorry If I misunderstood.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry if my explanation could be confusing. In the form when I put the value (i.e "hello") on input field with `id="TagId0"`, this value must be passed to the name of the next input field as written above. Hope I was clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `change` method to detect a change in the fields value. Then use the `attr` method to change the name. Hope I understood correctly. Here is the modified [JSFIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qN3eu/3/).

```
$(document).on('change', '#InputsWrapper .inputID', function(){
    thisVal = $(this).val();
    thisName = $(this).siblings('.inputVal').attr('name');
    newName = thisName.replace('[tags][', '[tags][' + thisVal);
    $(this).siblings('.inputVal').attr('name', newName);
});
```

Don't forget to press enter after change the field value :)

Edit: I also added two classes to the fields you are appending. `.inputID` and `.inputVal`. I hope this helps!

Comment: In the fiddle the input value with `id=TagValue` has this `name="metrics[0][tags][][0]"` but when i fill the previous input field with a value, this name won't change if I see with Chrome inspect element. For example I put `"ch"` on input field with `id="TagId0"` but I won't see `"ch"` on the name of the last input

Comment: Oh I understand now, I changed the wrong input. Working on it now.

Comment: It works, thanks, but there's a problem. I'm sorry I wasn't specific in the question. I need that only this field change. Instead with your function also the first input field change when I fill it. For example: `<input type="text" name="metrics[0][AIENR]" value="Text 0">` and I don't want that will happens. I think will enough modify the value on the first line of your function, isn'it?

Comment: I modified it, and updated the jsfiddle. See if that works for you.

Comment: Now it works, but it's not enough for me, sorry man. The problem is that if I click "Add Tag" to add other two fields (id and value) the function will take also the new id value, while I want that every time i add a new id, the value will take it's relative id.

Comment: I'm looking at it now. I will see what I can do :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a bit newbie of jQuery and web developing

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, because it saves the first value inserted, for instance if in the second case I digit "mq"  the resulting html code will be: `<input type="text" class="inputVal" id="TagValue" name="metrics[0][tags][mqch][0]">` Where `ch` is the first value inserted, but I think is a silly problem

Comment: Sorry I feel silly. Try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qN3eu/5/, I gave the 2 inputs a wrapper and that solved it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and also for your time! :) it works like I desired to :)

Answer (score 1):

you can write id of field something like TagId-0 and some common class like tagfield,so that u can split the value to get the index an then access it using the class

```
$(".tagfield").keypress(function() {
 var id=parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("-"));
      $(this).siblings().attr("name","metrics["+id+"][tags]["+$(this).val()+"][0]");
});
```